# Moving Magento 1.9 to a new server causes Base table or view already exists error

Tags: magento-1.9

the website was functionnal on the old server, I just copied the files and recreated the database, but I get this error :

```
a:5:{i:0;s:1610:"Error in file: "/home/encrefrezal2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/sql/catalog_setup/install-1.6.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'catalog_product_entity' already exists, query was: CREATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity` (
  `entity_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Entity ID' ,
  `entity_type_id` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Entity Type ID' ,
  `attribute_set_id` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Attribute Set ID' ,
  `type_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL default 'simple' COMMENT 'Type ID' ,
  `sku` varchar(64) NULL COMMENT 'SKU' ,
  `has_options` smallint NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Has Options' ,
  `required_options` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Required Options' ,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Creation Time' ,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Update Time' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  INDEX `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_ENTITY_TYPE_ID` (`entity_type_id`),
  INDEX `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID` (`attribute_set_id`),
  INDEX `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_SKU` (`sku`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_TYPE_ID_EAV_ENTT_TYPE_ENTT_TYPE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_type_id`) REFERENCES `eav_entity_type` (`entity_type_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) COMMENT='Catalog Product Table' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci";i:1;s:1014:"#0 /home/encrefrezal2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /home/encrefrezal2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.6.0.0.19.1.2')
#2 /home/encrefrezal2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.6.0.0.19.1.2')
#3 /home/encrefrezal2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /home/encrefrezal2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(428): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /home/encrefrezal2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /home/encrefrezal2/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /home/encrefrezal2/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

I read that it has something to do with core_resource table, can someone tell what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error say : Magento want to update your core_resource with your *install-1.6.0.0.php* file, and so it try to create a table which already exist.

You can remove this table if you don't want to keep the data inside and if you want to pass your script.

Or you can go in your code_resource table and for your catalog_setup code (
`select * from core_resource where code = "catalog_setup"`
), put the version and the data_version to "1.6.0.0". So your Magento will not try to create your table again because it's thought it already did that.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. Since I was "cloning" the website, I thought Magento will not try to process the tables.